# guvc video capture commandline

Tags: command-line, webcam, guvcview

I know how to use the -h option, I just don't see any commands to start video capture with file incrementation unless I press the video capture button.

**What is the command line to start video capture guvcview using filename incrementation.**

The option **`-n, --video=FILENAME Video File name (capture from start)`** will start video capture, however, the filename is overwritten unless the gui capture button is used.

Answer (score 4):

In order to run guvcview capture from command line you need to send a SIGUSR1 signal to the running application. First start it:

```
guvcview --no_display -n capture_file.avi
```

Then from a second shell window type the following:

```
killall -s USR1 guvcview
```

This will start a video capture and save the file in the current directory. You need to combine these 2 lines into a shell script if you want to run it automatically. Information from guvcview output:

```
GUVCVIEW Signals:
SIGUSR1: Video stop/start capture
SIGUSR2: Image capture
SIGINT (ctrl+c): Exit
```

Comment: It works as a script, however, I would also like to have filename incrementation so that I don't have to manually change the filename each time myself. Thanks.

Comment: Then you can update the script to check using a for loop if the files exists and increment the new file name with 1 to bypass overwriting the existing files.

Comment: really, you don't have to send a SIGUSR1 signal; to start video capture (see `guvcview -h | grep "capture from start"` ) `guvcview -n capture_file.avi` does the same thing

Comment: @mchid:  
guvcview -h
`-n,--photo_total=TOTAL                 :total number of captured photos)`